# Update viewmodel based on MainWindow event

Tags: wpf, prism, viewmodel

I have a UdpClient, firing off a DataRecevied event on my MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static YakUdpClient ClientConnection = new YakUdpClient();
    public ClientData;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        ClientData = new ClientData();
        ClientConnection.OnDataReceived += ClientConnectionOnDataReceived;
    }

    private void ClientConnectionOnDataReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
    {
        ClientData.Users = messageEvenArgs.ConnectedUsers;
    }
}
```

My ClientData and User classes look as follow:

```
public class ClientData
{
    public List<User> Users {get;set;)
}

public class User
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

On my MainWindow, I have a UserControl called `UserListView` which has a ViewModel called `UserListViewModel`

The ViewModel looks as follow:

```
public class UserListViewModel: BindableBase
{
    public UserListViewModel()
    {
        //I am sure there are better ways of doing this :(
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).ClientData.Users
    });

    private ObservableCollection<User> _users;
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get{ return _users;}
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._users, value); }
    }
}
```

The difficulty I have here, is when the `ClientConnectionOnDataReceived` event on the MainWindow gets fired, I would like to update my `ClientData` class, My Viewmodel should then somehow be notified that the list changed, and subsequently update my UI.

Can anyone give me a solid example of how to achieve this using MVVM (Prism) in WPF?

I am new to MVVM, so i am still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Take a look into PubSub events using an EventAggregator (sometimes called "Messenger"); it will decouple the tight logic against your ViewModels, and allow for scaleability/change. I would recommend looking at Prism's EventAggregator: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample

Comment: Also, Prism is useful for wiring up ViewModels - there's a `BindableBase` class, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` nicely, which will be able to update your views when something changes in the ViewModel. *Just to clarify - I'm not affiliated with/work for Prism :)*

Comment: @GeoffJames, you will notice that my `UserListViewModel` inherits from `BindableBase`. Apologies, i am using prism... updated my post to reflect so. All my reasearch on MVVM had me confused there for a second

Comment: Just spotted that, my bad entirely! *Goes and gets another coffee...* Just a faux-pas: When you're `new`ing up your `ClientData` class, you're not instantiating it as a variable..? Further, it might be worth passing the reference of this variable to your `UserListViewModel`'s ctor - then, you could set a private field of the `ClientData` instance being passed in, and listen to the `OnDataReceived` event that way? Instead of doing it from the `MainWindow`

Comment: @GeoffJames, The ClientData class is referenced in more than one UserControl, so typically i would like my MainWindow to update the ClientData class, and my diffrent ViewModels to retrieve there data from the CLientData class

Comment: *Goes and gets yet another coffee* Fair enough. write some Services to deal with the `ClientData`, and then use IoC and Dependency Injection in order to create just the one instance of the service to be used across the app. That way, you can just create a ctor with the interface to take, and your IoC container (Prism do a good DI/IoC :)) will take care of the rest :) You could also just instantiate the one service at base level, and all your ViewModels/other classes could use PubSub to listen to events that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there's no obvious reason why the main window should do the subscription.

I'd go for something like this:

- create a service that encapsulates the subscription (and subscribes in its constructor)
- register that as a singleton
- have it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (to notify consumers of a change to `Users`)
- inject the service into `UserListViewModel` and observe the `Users` property (see [PropertyObserver](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/))
- when `Users` in the service changes, update `Users` in the user list view model

and best of all, no need for `ObservableCollection` here :-)

EDIT: example:

```
interface IUserService : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<User> Users
    {
        get;
    }
}

class YakUdpService : BindableBase, IUserService
{
    private readonly YakUdpClient _yakUdpClient;
    private IReadOnlyCollection<User> _users;

    public YakUdpService()
    {
        _yakUdpClient = new YakUdpClient();
        _yakUdpClient.OnDataReceived += ( s, e ) => Users = e.ConnectedUsers;
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }
        private set
        {
            SetProperty( ref _users, value );
        }
    }
}

class UserListViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IReadOnlyCollection<UserViewModel> _users;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly PropertyObserver<IUserService> _userServiceObserver;

    public UserListViewModel( IUserService userService )
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _userServiceObserver = new PropertyObserver<IUserService>( userService );
        _userServiceObserver.RegisterHandler( x => x.Users, () => Users = _userService.Users.Select( x => new UserViewModel( x ) ).ToList() );
        //                                                                                                ^^^ should use factory in real code
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<UserViewModel> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }
        private set
        {
            SetProperty( ref _users, value );
        }
    }
}
```

and then register the service

```
Container.RegisterType<IUserService, YakUdpService>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
```

in your bootstrapper or your module's initialization.

Comment: @GeoffJames also suggested this in one of his comments above, is there any chance you can give me give me a minimal example of how to achieve this?