# How to share multiple ObservableCollections with multiple ViewModels?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am writing a program with 4 Views: **CompanyView**, **MembersView**, **WeeksView** and **ReportsView**. Each has a corresponding ViewModel and Model. I have used PRISM BindableBase to create the ViewModels. The data binds correctly.

- **CompanyViewModel** contains an Object of type **Company**.
- **MembersViewModel** contains an ObservableCollection of **Member** Objects.
- **WeeksViewModel** contains an ObservableCollection of **Week** Objects.

Navigation is performed via top buttons in the MainWindow, with *any View able to be selected at any time*.

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<CompanyView>("CompanyView");
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MembersView>("MembersView");
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<WeeksView>("WeeksView");
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ReportsView>("ReportsView");
```

The problem is that **WeeksViewModel** must *also* have access to the **Members ObservableCollection**. And the **ReportsViewModel** must *also* have access to the **Company** **Object**, **Members ObservableCollection** and the **Weeks ObservableCollection**.

I am not sure how to implement this. How can I easily share the data between the ViewModels?

I have tried using the **PRISM IEventAggregator** to Publish the **ObservableCollections** when they are updated, and this works, however the View must first be accessed before it can listen to the Event. If the user has not clicked on "Weeks" view before, the updated **MembersCollection** wont reach the **WeeksView**. Could I pre-initialise the Views? How would I do this?

I followed the **MVVM Made Simple with Prism - Webinar**  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY) and discovered the same problem written in the comments. Brian Lagunas suggests the only way to fix this is via Navigation Parameters:

> I have a small problem with the UpdateEvent passing the message from ViewAViewModel to ViewBViewModel. It doesn't seem to work if I have not visited ViewB, I assume this is because the ViewBViewModel has not yet been instantiated until the view for it has been loaded at least once.
>
> Anybody got any ideas on this, I assume instantiating all viewmodels before they're needed is a bad idea, so how can you get default information into a viewmodel from other viewmodels before it's been instantiated?
>
> > Brian Lagunas: The only way to do it is to pass that information as a parameter when you navigate to ViewBViewModel.

I have considered using Navigation Parameters, but it seems you must know from WHERE to WHERE you are navigating. E.G. From **MembersView** > **WeeksView**, pass the **Members Collection** as a Parameter. But users can naviagate in any order, including directly to **WeeksView** on program load. e.g. How does the **WeeksView** get the **Members Collection** if they came from the Company View? Company does not know about Members Collection.

I am open to other ideas, I have researched far and wide and am completely stuck :-(

Thanks very much for your ideas and help!
Kind Regards,
Damian

Comment: out of curiousity, are the users able to have seperate views open at the same time? I.e. is there a way for the WeeksView and MembersView to be open and visible at the same time?

Comment: You can also use Prism's [region context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec6) for that.

Comment: You should have a main viewmodel which creates its child viewmodels and sets up anything that's shared among them. This approach simplifies navigation as well. You're facing an artificial problem created by PRISM. The simplest solution is not to create the problem.

Comment: No need to have the separate views open at the same time. I like the idea of Main and Child ViewModels. Simple is always best. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome but please remember to accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Hi mm8, I am trying to get this to work, but having lots of problems. Is there an example or sample code you know I could look at? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that WeeksViewModel must also have access to the Members ObservableCollection. And the ReportsViewModel must also have access to the Company Object, Members ObservableCollection and the Weeks ObservableCollection.
>
> I am not sure how to implement this. How can I easily share the data between the ViewModels?

You could use a single view model with properties for each specific view model and the common properties to be shared across two or more view models, e.g.:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public CompanyViewModel CompanyViewModel { get; set; }
    public MembersViewModel MembersViewModel { get; set; }
    public WeeksViewModel WeeksViewModel { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Members> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Then each of the child views can inherit the `DataContext` of the parent window and bind to any property they want across all view model types.

The other option would be to pass information back and forth between the view models, either using direct references, an event aggregator or a shared service.

But it seems kind of pointless to desperately try to separate the logic between the view models if they still must access properties of each other. So I would probably go with the first approach.

Comment: Creating a `MainViewModel` that exposes a `MembersViewModel` and a `Members` collection and passing that `MainViewModel` as data context to the `MembersView` to have it bind to `MembersViewModel.SomeProperty` and also to `Members` is kinda weird...

Comment: No, but getting an ObservableCollection from a service (!) certainly is.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is from `ObjectModel` namespace and is by no means WPF- or UI-only. There's nothing wrong with using `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `INotifyCollectionChanged` outside your view models.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work, but having lots of problems... Will I have to redo my current Prism navigation method? Is there an example or sample code you know I could look at? Thanks!

Comment: Just create a new class and move the shared properties to this one and bind the specific properties like {Binding CompanyViewModel.CompanyName}. You will need to provide a sample of your current code for me to be able to give you any further suggestions.

Comment: OK, I've created another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232795/c-sharp-mvvm-prism-creating-parent-child-viewmodels-to-allow-sharing-of-observab and will accept this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest to make the `Company`, `ObservableCollection<Week>` and `ObservableCollection<Member>` come from one or more services.

The `WeeksViewModel` then receives `ObservableCollection<Week>` and `ObservableCollection<Member>` from the service(s) and processes the data for consumption by the `WeeksView`. The `ReportsViewModel` processes `Company`, `ObservableCollection<Week>` and `ObservableCollection<Member>` for consumption by the `ReportsView`... If someone adds a `Member`, he does that through the service possessing the `ObservableCollection<Member>`, and all view models that received the `ObservableCollection<Member>` from that service, will get a notification and update accordingly.

There's no need to pass data around between view models, because the view models *do not own the data*. All they ever do is transforming data from some data source for a view to display, and the other way round convert user actions to calls to a service that modifies the data.

The moment you have view models that own data, you get methods like `UpdateData` on the view models, and ultimately you end up with unintelligible spaghetti code of `UpdateThis` and `UpdateThat` or one mm8-style mega view model that's used by all views. You don't want that.

Comment: "Mega-style"? Did you miss the child properties?

Comment: Agreed! Manage data via the service.

Comment: Of course the data should be managed via services that the view model is injected with. But you must still expose the data from the view model to the view and this is what the question is about as I see it.

Comment: The question is about using the same data in multiple views, that is, view models. To achieve this, I suggest a service that provides the data to the different view models while you suggest a master-view model that owns the data and provides it to child view models. For me, this kind of data distribution is not a view models job. A view models job is to provide data to its own view.

Comment: No, I don't suggest that the master owns the data that are specific to the child views. Maybe you should read my answer once more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand how to create "services" that passes the data. Is there an example you could provide? Some sample code?

Comment: Have a look here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915353/update-viewmodel-based-on-mainwindow-event/38916743#38916743

Essentially, you register a singleton (the service) and inject it in all interested view models. You can refine it so that the service class implements multiple (lean) interfaces and each view model only gets exactly the functionality it needs (one might want to create appointments while another might just want to show the list of all appointments)...