# How to delete an entry in a ObservableCollection bound to a DataGrid from another view using DelegateCommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, prism

Right now I'm developing an C# WPF application using Prism Framework and Unity.

I have two views in my application. The first view contains a DataGrid bound to a ObservableCollection. The second view is a RibbonTab in a Ribbon which contains a few buttons.
My goal is that if you press the delete button on the RibbonTab the selected element of the DataGrid should be deleted. Now the problem is I also have viewmodels for each view. How do I solve my problem in a MVVM fashion way using Prism Framework?

I already tried to use a DelegateCommand written in the first viewmodel which a call in the second viewmodel using Unity. The command gets called but the DataGrid does not update. I also use RaisePropertyChanged(); in my ObservableCollection object...

SpottingsLogViewModel

```
namespace AirBase.Spottings.ViewModels
{
    public class SpottingsLogViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Properties
        private ObservableCollection<Spotting> list;

    public ObservableCollection<Spotting> List
    {
        get { return list; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref list, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("list");
        }
    }

    private int selectedIndex;

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedIndex, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("selectedIndex");
        }
    }

    private string selectedItem;

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedItem, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Fields
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private ISpottingsLogService _spottingsLogService;
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    public DelegateCommand AddItemCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand DeleteSelectedItemCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion



    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public SpottingsLogViewModel()
    {
        //_spottingsLogService = spottingsLogService;

        AddItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(Add);
        DeleteSelectedItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(Delete);

        List = new ObservableCollection<Spotting>();

        LoadSpottings();


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all entries found in the database.
    /// </summary>
    private void LoadSpottings()
    {
        AirBaseDbContext context = new AirBaseDbContext();

        // Display all Blogs from the database 
        var query = from s in context.Spottings
                    select s;

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Spotting spotting = new Spotting()
            {
                Registration = item.Registration,
                Aircraft = item.Aircraft,
                Airline = item.Airline,
                Location = item.Location,
                Date = item.Date
            };
            List.Add(spotting);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Only for testing purpose.
    /// </summary>
    private void Add()
    {
        Spotting spotting = new Spotting()
        {
            Registration = "LL",
            Aircraft = "737",
            Airline = "Lufthansa",
            Location = "EDDL",
            Date = new DateTime(2018, 07, 02)
        };
        List.Add(spotting);

        Console.WriteLine("Anzahl in der Liste: " + List.Count);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void Delete()
    {
        if(List.Count > 0)
            List.RemoveAt(SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

}

SpottingsTabViewModel

```
namespace AirBase.Spottings.ViewModels
{
    public class SpottingsTabViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        #region Properties
        private string _title ="Logbook";
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }
        #endregion

    #region Fields
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    public DelegateCommand AddCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public SpottingsTabViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
        //_eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        AddCommand = _container.Resolve<SpottingsLogViewModel>().AddItemCommand;
        DeleteCommand = _container.Resolve<SpottingsLogViewModel>().DeleteSelectedItemCommand;

    }
}
```

}

I have to mansion that both viewmodels and their views are in the same module.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the help center to see how to ask a good question. We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199892/how-to-share-multiple-observablecollections-with-multiple-viewmodels/46202680#46202680

Comment: Ok I try this solution although I'm not a Software Engineer and do not have that much experience in these design patterns which is the reason why I do not exactly know what to do. 

I mean my views are in one module I read that this is a common approach to communicate between modules.

Comment: I solved the problem and it was relatively easy, easier I thought.

A big Thank You to Haukinger!